# Parallax Template div overlay that doesnt scroll with the rest of page

Tags: css

I made a simple parrallex template for a friend of mine and i'm trying to add a layer ontop (with smoke)

when I scroll the page the smoke layer doesn't scroll up with the page, it just sort of dissapears, the logo div scrolls as it should but not the smoke layer,

my example can be found here:

www.junkjuice.co.uk

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What kind of effect are you trying to achieve here? If you want the smoke to scroll up with the first slide then you can just remove the `fixed` property in your background

Comment: i cant see the fixed property anywhere, yes I want the smoke layer (div) to scroll up with the first slide as the logo in the centre does.